# Arrow between two chemfig structures

Tags: chemfig

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{[:-210]N*6((-C(=[:-90]S(-[:-60,,,,->]Hg(-[:180]R)(-Cl)))(-NH(-[:-90]NH_2(-[:-120,.8,,<-]))))------)}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

I want to draw arrow between two chemfig structures as per below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). This isn't a "Please do my work for me" site! What do you have so far? Try to create ...

Comment: You were close! There is a comma missing in `[:-120,.8,,<-]`, this should be also rather be `[:-120,.8,,,->]`. Then, it should be `[:-216]N*5`, not `[:-210]N*6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

  \chemfig{*5(--N(-C(=[6]S?)-NH-[6,,,1]NH_2-[:-120,,,,{->}]Hg?[,,{->}](-[4]R)-Cl)---)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you replace `->` with `-latex`,  you will have filled arrow heads.